# How to access framebuffer from CPU in Direct3D 11?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, direct3d11

I am creating a simple framework for teaching fundamental graphics concepts under C++/D3D11. The framework is required to enable direct manipulation of the screen raster contents via a simple interface function (e.g. `Putpixel( x,y,r,g,b )`).

Under D3D9 this was a relatively simple goal achieved by allocating a surface buffer on the heap where the CPU would compose a surface. Then the backbuffer would be locked and the heap buffer's contents transferred to the backbuffer. As I understand it, it is not possible to access the backbuffer directly from the CPU under D3D11. One must prepare a texture resource and then draw it to the backbuffer via some fullscreen geometry.

I have considered two systems for such a procedure. The first comprises a `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` texture and a `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` texture. The staging texture is first mapped and then drawn to from the CPU. When the scene is complete, the staging texture is unmapped and copied to the default texture with `CopyResource` (which uses the GPU to perform the copy if I am not mistaken), and then the default texture is drawn to the backbuffer via a fullscreen textured quad.

The second system comprises a `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` texture and a frame buffer allocated on the heap. When the scene is composed, the dynamic texture is mapped, the contents of the heap buffer are copied over to the dynamic texture via the CPU, the dynamic texture is unmapped, and then it is drawn to the backbuffer via a fullscreen textured quad.

I was under the impression that textures created with read and write access and `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` would reside in system memory, but the performance tests I have run seem to indicate that this is not the case. Namely, drawing a simple 200x200 filled rectangle via CPU is about 3x slower with the staging texture than with the heap buffer (exact same disassembly for both cases (a tight `rep stos` loop)), strongly hinting that the staging texture resides in the graphics adapter memory.

I would prefer to use the staging texture system, since it would allow both the work of rendering to the backbuffer and the work of copying from system memory to graphics memory to be offloaded onto the GPU. However, I would like to prioritize CPU access speed over such an ability in any case.

So what method method would be optimal for this usage case? Any hints, modifications of my two approaches, or suggestions of altogether different approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamic and staging are both likely to be in system memory, but their is good chance that your issue, is write combined memory. It is a cache mode where single writes are coalesced together, but if you attempt to read, because it is un-cached, each load pay the price of a full memory access. You even have to be very careful, because a c++ `*data=something;` may sometime also leads to unwanted reads.

There is nothing wrong with a dynamic texture, the GPU can read system memory, but you need to be careful, create a few of them, and cycle each frame with a map_nooverwrite, to inhibit the costly driver buffer renaming of the discard. Of course, never do a map in read and write, only write, or you will introduce gpu/cpu sync and kill the parallelism.

Last, if you want a persistent surface and only a few putpixel a frame (or even a lot of them), i would go with an unordered access view and a compute shader that consume a buffer of pixel position with colors to update. That buffer would be a dynamic buffer with nooverwrite mapping, once again. With that solution, the main surface will reside in video memory.

On a personal note, i would not even bother to teach cpu surface manipulation, this is almost always a bad practice and a performance killer, and not the way to go in a modern gpu architecture. This was not a fundamental graphic concept a decade ago already.

Comment: It seems odd that the driver would specify write-combining for memory that is flagged for both reading and writing by the CPU. Thanks for your advice on the dynamic texture, I will try your method of creating multiple textures and cycling with nooverwrite. Also, the goal is not to teach CPU surface manipulation, but rather to teach fundamental concepts (mathematics and algorithms) of 2D/3D raster graphics in a hands-on manner.

Comment: every teaching fundamental graphics book I have ever read has always done things the slowest way possible. I wish the authors put in some effort to study high performing real world code from real apps, and taught that instead. thanks for your time to answer galop1n, I learnt more from your answer than entire books.